# Change a string using str_replace() Function with PHP

Tags: php, string, str-replace

How can I change this:

```
[ "Aluno1": 65.8, "Aluno2": 0.3, "Aluno3": 34.9 ]
```

to have this:

```
['dafa', 43.00],['adfasdf', 13.00],['cu', 0.00]
```

maybe changing `:` to `,` and `,` to `][`, but how can I do that using `str_replace()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer. In fact it's more complicated that simply replace ":" to "," for example. Try this :

```
$Stringtoreplace = '[ "Aluno1": 65.8, "Aluno2": 0.3, "Aluno3": 34.9 ]';


$NewStringReplace = str_replace('":','",',$Stringtoreplace);
$NewStringReplace = str_replace(', "','],["',$NewStringReplace);

//If you want to change every double quotes to single remove line below
//$NewStringReplace = str_replace('"',"'",$NewStringReplace);

echo $NewStringReplace;
// echo : [ "Aluno1", 65.8],["Aluno2", 0.3],["Aluno3", 34.9 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `str_replace()` you can wrap what you want to change in % and then apply. Example below;

```
$old_sentence = "My name is %name%";
$new_sentence = str_replace('%name%', 'ADAM', $old_sentence);
echo $new_sentence;
```

"My name is ADAM"

Hope this gives you an idea of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need json_decode($array);

so like:

```
$your_array=[ "Aluno1": 65.8, "Aluno2": 0.3, "Aluno3": 34.9 ];
json_decode($your_array);
```

But json is so nice to have arrays in why convert it back?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to parse a string to a function in jQuery, but I'm getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :". I tested with the second string and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, thank you guys. I got it by using the following code:

```
$old_sentence = "[ "Aluno1": 65.8, "Aluno2": 0.3, "Aluno3": 34.9 ]";
$new_sentence = str_replace(',', '],[', $old_sentence);
$output = str_replace(':', ',', $new_sentence);
echo $output;
```

Comment: You have to escape your double quotes... Here your code means nothing. $old_sentence wont work here